# vector product defined on kronecker delta

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, vector-calculus

I have some vectors such as :

```
a={{0}, {0}, {0}};
b={{1}, {1}, {1}};
c={{1}, {1}, {0}};
```

I wanted to product `a` by `a` with the result `1`, also the product of `b` and `b` must be `1`, but the product of `c` and `b` (c and a) must yield `0`, and so on. As a matter of fact, the desire result is as Kronecker delta, but I do not know how I can define a function with this characterization.

However, Jens' answer [how-to-define-an-orthogonal-basis-in-the-right-way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73990/how-to-define-an-orthogonal-basis-in-the-right-way) could help, but it is different in details, because, in my calculation any vector does not have a specified name same as `x, y, z`. In my large calculation, any vector acts with their component in any iteration and they do not have a name in every time. For example in  [how-to-define-an-orthogonal-basis-in-the-right-way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73990/how-to-define-an-orthogonal-basis-in-the-right-way) output you can write:

```
tensorExpand[Dot[x, y]]
0

tensorExpand[Dot[x, x]]
1
```

But directly:

```
tensorExpand[Dot[{{1}, {1}, {1}}, {{0}, {0}, {0}}]]
```

can't manipulate.

Comment: Question is very unclear. What do components of your "vector" mean? Are you inventing scalar product? Why `Dot` is no good?

Comment: Because, dot ('.') ,sums all product component after multiplication, but I didn't sum of them

Comment: @BlacKow, please note 'I THINK, question is very unclear', because someone maybe understands completely without any ambiguous deduction.

Comment: What about `SameQ`?

Comment: Maybe something like `delta[v1_, v2_] := Times @@ MapThread[Boole[Equal[##]] &, {v1, v2}]`.  I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Or even `delta[v1_, v2_] := Boole[Equal[v1, v2]]`...

Comment: SameQ could help but is not straightforward,

Comment: Boole@SameQ[#1,#2]&

Comment: @ chuy, this comment completely satisfy my needs.

Comment: Maybe the following will be better suited for your ultimate goal (this is just a guess):  [How to define an orthogonal basis in the right way?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73990/how-to-define-an-orthogonal-basis-in-the-right-way)

Comment: @Jens, I could not use of what you answer on the 'How to define an orthogonal basis in the right way'? However, that answer is so complete but many of them are not directly related to my question.