# Vector calculations in unspecified dimension

Tags: vector

So I would like to be able to do operations on vectors, *while leaving the dimension $N$ of the vector space unspecified*.

As a simple example, I would like to be able to define the unit vector $e_i = (0,\dots 1,\dots,0)$ which has as its only non-vanishing entry a $1$ in the $i$th slot. Then I would like to be able to let Mathematica compute the inner product $e_i\cdot e_j$; the output of Mathematica should be something like $\delta_{ij}$ (which equals $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ if $i\neq j$).

When the dimension $N$ is defined as an explicit number, one can of course just define the explicit vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$ and compute the inner product, which will again be an explicit vector. But I would like to do the calculation for general $N$.

Is there a way in Mathematica to achieve this?

Comment: Related: [How to define an orthogonal basis in the right way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73990/245) and [How do I simplify a vector expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21197/245)

Comment: It looks like you're talking about Euclidean vector spaces. If you're interested in other operations beyond dot products, please specify with an example of what you have tried.

Comment: @Jens In the end what I want to do is calculate commutators between $N\times N$ matrices, where $N$ is again unspecified. But I imagine this will be easy to do once I understand how to implement the simple example in my question.

Comment: Actually, the way it's current written it could also be a duplicate of [Defining quantum-mechanical Bra and Ket operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84619/245). You'll need additional definitions for outer products (or dual vectors) to generate matrices in your basis, but it can be done analogously, using `TagSetDelayed`. It would be easier to help if you gave a more complete example.

Comment: Concerning commutators: if that's what you ultimately want, the relevant link may be [Defining a non-commutative operator algebra in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22824/245)